# How to get the checkbox value of a list in asp mvc

Tags: javascript, html, asp.net-mvc

I use the below code to have a list with dynamic count. when I get the model in my action the checkbox values are `null`(even when i check them).

my model:

```
public partial class Job_SharhVazife
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Job_Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Asli { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Mostamar { get; set; }
    public Nullable<int> Dore { get; set; }
    public Nullable<bool> Tafviz { get; set; }

    public virtual Job_MainJob Job_MainJob { get; set; }
    public virtual Job_SharhVazife_Dore Job_SharhVazife_Dore { get; set; }
}
public class AllDataOfMainJob
{
     public IEnumerable<Job_SharhVazife> Job_SharhVazife { get; set; }
}
```

my html code:

```
@model JobWebApplication.Models.AllDataOfMainJob
...
    <div class="form-group">
        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Job_SharhVazife, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
            <div class="col-md-10">
                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table id="tblSharhVazife" class="table">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>@Html.Label("Row")</th>
                                <th>@Html.Label("Header1-text")</th>
                                <th>@Html.Label("Header2-checkbox")</th>
                                <th>@Html.Label("Header3-checkbox")</th>
                                <th>@Html.Label("Header4-dropdown")</th>
                                <th>@Html.Label("Header5-checkbox")</th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody>
                            @if (Model.Job_SharhVazife != null)
                            {
                                for (int i = 0; i < Model.Job_SharhVazife.Count(); i++)
                                {
                                <tr>
                                    <td>@((i + 1).ToString())</td>
                                    <td><input class="form-control text-box single-line valid" id=@("Job_SharhVazife_" + @i + "__Name") name="Job_SharhVazife[@i].Name" type="text" value="@Model.Job_SharhVazife.ToList()[i].Name"></td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="checkbox">
                                            <label>
                                                <input type="checkbox" id=@("Job_SharhVazife_" + @i + "__Asli") name="Job_SharhVazife[@i].Asli" value="" @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Job_SharhVazife.ToList()[i].Asli.ToString()) && bool.Parse(Model.Job_SharhVazife.ToList()[i].Asli.ToString()))
                                                { <text> checked="checked" </text> } /><span class="text"></span>
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <div class="checkbox">
                                            <label>
                                                <input type="checkbox" id=@("Job_SharhVazife_" + @i + "__Mostamar") name="Job_SharhVazife[@i].Mostamar" value="" @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Job_SharhVazife.ToList()[i].Mostamar.ToString()) && bool.Parse(Model.Job_SharhVazife.ToList()[i].Mostamar.ToString()))
                                                { <text> checked="checked" </text> } /><span class="text"></span>
                                            </label>
                                        </div>
                                    </td>
                                    <td>
                                        <select id=@("Job_SharhVazife_" + @i + "__Dore") name="Job_SharhVazife[@i].Dore" width="100% !important" class="valid">
                                                @Html.Raw(GetSharheVazifeDoreDDL(Model.Job_SharhVazife.ToList()[i].Dore.ToString()))
                                            </select>
                                        </td>
                                        <td>
                                            <div class="checkbox">
                                                <label>
                                                    <input type="checkbox" id=@("Job_SharhVazife_" + @i + "__Tafviz") name="Job_SharhVazife[@i].Tafviz" value="" @if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Model.Job_SharhVazife.ToList()[i].Tafviz.ToString()) && bool.Parse(Model.Job_SharhVazife.ToList()[i].Tafviz.ToString()))
                                                    { <text> checked="checked" </text> } /><span class="text"></span>
                                                </label>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    }
                                }
                            </tbody>
                        </table>
                    </div>
                    <input id="btnAddSharhVazife" type="button" value="+" onclick="AddSharhVazife();" />
                    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(model => model.Job_SharhVazife, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                </div>
            </div>

...
    <script>
      function AddSharhVazife() {
                var m = $('#tblSharhVazife tbody tr:last-child input:last-child').attr('name');
                var index = 0;
                if (m != null && m.length > 0) {
                    index = m.split('Job_SharhVazife[')[1].replace('].Name', '');
                    index++;
                }

                var tableBody = $('#tblSharhVazife tbody');
                var htmlSharhVazifeDoreItems = '@Html.Raw(SharhVazifeDoreItems)';

                var html = "<tr>" +
                    "<td>" + (index+1).toString() + "</td>" +
                    "<td><input class=\"form-control text-box single-line valid\" id=\"Job_SharhVazife_" + index + "__Name\" name=\"Job_SharhVazife[" + index + "].Name\" type=\"text\" value=\"\"></td>" +
                    "<td><div class=\"checkbox\"><label><input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"Job_SharhVazife_"  + index + "__Asli\" name=\"Job_SharhVazife[" + index + "].Asli\" value=\"1\" /><span class=\"text\">اصلی </span></label></div></td>" +
                    "<td><div class=\"checkbox\"><label><input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"Job_SharhVazife_"  + index + "__Mostamar\" name=\"Job_SharhVazife[" + index + "].Mostamar\" value=\"2\" /><span class=\"text\"></span></label></div></td>" +
                    "<td><select id=\"Job_SharhVazife_" + index + "__Dore\" name=\"Job_SharhVazife["     + index + "].Dore\" width=\"100% !important\" class=\"valid\">" + htmlSharhVazifeDoreItems + "</select></td>" +
                    "<td><div class=\"checkbox\"><label><input type=\"checkbox\" id=\"Job_SharhVazife_"  + index + "__Tafviz\" name=\"Job_SharhVazife[" + index + "].Tafviz\" value=\"3\" /><span class=\"text\"></span></label></div></td>" +
                    "</tr>";
                tableBody.append(html);
            };
    </script>
```

Comment: can you share Job_SharhVazife model ?

Comment: @Ahmed Ragheb I updated my question.

Comment: you can't create a checkbox for a string type like string. checkbox is for boolean properties.

Comment: There is so much wrong with your code its hard to know where to start. First, you cannot a check box to a `nullable bool` (a checkbox has 2 states, and a `bool?` has 3 states). You cannot use a `for` loop on a `IEnumerable<T>` property to generate form controls for collection. You need  a custom `EditorTemplate` or the property needs to be `IList<T>`. You generating manual html (and writing 3 or 4 times as much code to make it not work) instead of binding to your model. And your not even giving the checkboxes a value so they never post a value.

Answer (score 1):

I test the code and I replace HTML with MVC razor html Helper

```
@Html.CheckBoxFor(x => Model.Job_SharhVazife[i].Asli)
```

and for all properties and It working now, But you have to change `Job_SharhVazife` to be `List` not `IEnumerable` and all `bool? to bool` and you can add `false` as a default value.

Comment: @Stephen did you read my answer ? I recommend to change bool? to bool with default value and IEnumerable to list.

Comment: Sorry, I missed the `bool? to bool` bit :)